# Categories not appearing in playa:children

Tags: playa, categories

One of the main templates on my site, the product page, has a single products channel entry, and up to 3 playa children (also products). I'm trying to get the categories for playa children. Here's my test code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1" status="open|wide|feature|glory"}
    <h1>Main Product: {title}</h1>
    {exp:playa:children field="also_like" status="open|wide"}
        <h1><a href="{title_permalink='site/product'}">{title}</a></h1> 
        <div class="age">Age: {categories show_group="5" limit="1" note="age range"}{category_name}{/categories}</div>
        <div class="environ">Env: {categories show_group="6" limit="1" note="environment"}{category_name}{/categories}</div>
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Another page manages to display the categories, but it's directly from the channel:entries tag, rather than going through the playa:children.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NotoriousWebmaster -

Playa disables categories by default. You'll need to add disable= to over-ride the parameter.

```
{exp:playa:children field="also_like" status="open|wide" disable="members"}
```

or similar.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: d'Oh! I knew that! I'd read it somewhere along the way. Thanks.

Comment: Woot! Happy to help. Have a great weekend!