# Does Playa Children tag support the Categories variable pair from EE Channel Entries module

Tags: playa

The below code is parsing the Title & ENTRY ID variables but not the categories pair. The Playa documentation says it supports "nearly all" variables etc for the EE Channel Entries module.

```
{exp:playa:children field="log_skill"}
                            <p>{title}</p>
                            <p>{entry_id}</p>
                            <p>{categories}{category_name}{/categories}</p>
                        {/exp:playa:children}
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer on this post : [Categories not appearing in playa:children](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9756/categories-not-appearing-in-playachildren)

Playa disables categories by default so you need to explicitly name them.